# Determine whether date contains day or only month information

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to know if a `moment` object was created with both `day` and `month`.

**Example**

```
const date1 = moment("2018-08");
const date2 = moment("2018-08-01");

/* Determine if date1 was set with a day or not */
```

Comment: did you meant year and month?

Comment: Why don't you figure that out from the input values?

Comment: @charlietfl aah that might be better, not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`creationData()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/) to get the format used to create the moment object:

> After a moment object is created, all of the inputs can be accessed with `creationData()` method:
>
> ```
> moment("2013-01-02", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).creationData() === {
>     input: "2013-01-02",
>     format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
>     locale: Locale obj,
>     isUTC: false,
>     strict: true
> }
> ```

In your case, you can use something like

```
if( date1.creationData().format.includes('DD') )
```

Note that `date1.creationData().format` can be `undefined`.

---

Here I wrote a function that takes in account more edge cases (invalid moments, moment objects created from JS date or unix timestamps) using [`creationData()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/), [`parsingFlags()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) and `invalidAt()`:

```js
function isDaySet(m){
  if( moment.isMoment(m) ){
    if( !m.isValid() ){
      return m.invalidAt() > 2;
    }
  
    let creationData = m.creationData();
    if( creationData.format && creationData.format.includes('DD') ){
      return true;
    }
    let parsingFlags = m.parsingFlags();
    if( !parsingFlags.iso &&
        typeof creationData.input === 'string' ){
      let mFormatted = m.format('YYYY-MM-D');
      return creationData.input.includes(mFormatted);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

let arr = [
  moment("2018-08"),
  moment("2018-08-01"),
  moment("2018-08-1"),
  moment("2018-08-01 11"),
  moment("01 02 2018", "DD MM YYYY"),
  moment(1515424366),
  moment("2018-08-01 27:77"),
  moment("2018-Marbruary-01", 'YYYY-MMMM-DD'),
  moment('Marbruary', 'MMMM')
];

arr.forEach((m) => {
  console.log(isDaySet(m)); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the format of the input date like this.

```
const date1 = moment("2018-08");
const date2 = moment("2018-08-01");
date1._f // "YYYY-MM"
date2._f // "YYYY-MM-DD"

if ( date1._f == "YYYY-MM") { ... }
```

Comment: @NealVDV moment version?

Comment: Do not use [internal properties](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) like `_f`. Moreover this will give wrong result for objects like `moment("01 02 2018", "DD MM YYYY")`.